# Git merge spontaneously deletes file

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have two branches.  There's a file, present in both branches.  It has not been changed since before the two branches diverged.  When I merge one branch into the other, git deletes the file.  I can't see a reason for it to do so.  Consider the following console log, where I check the presence of the file in both branches, then attempt the merge, and show the file has now been deleted.  (I have redacted particular details, but the order of events remains unchanged, and I assure you that every file listed in the staged changes section was a .swift file, unlike the deleted file in question.)

```sh
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
$ ll PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved 
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  USER  603 Apr 00 00:00 PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved
$ git checkout feature/FEATURE
Switched to branch 'feature/FEATURE'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/FEATURE'.
$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ ll PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved 
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  USER  603 Apr 00 00:00 PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved
$ git checkout feature/FEATURE
Switched to branch 'feature/FEATURE'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/FEATURE'.
$ git status
On branch feature/FEATURE
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/FEATURE'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ ll PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved 
-rw-r--r--  1 USER  USER  603 Apr 00 00:00 PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved
$ git merge develop
Auto-merging PROJECT.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in PROJECT.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
On branch feature/FEATURE
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/FEATURE'.

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:

    new file:   PROJECT/PATH/SOME_SWIFT_FILES.swift
    modified:   PROJECT/PATH/SOME_OTHER_SWIFT_FILES.swift

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   PROJECT.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved

$ ll PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved 
ls: PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved: No such file or directory
$
```

Why is it doing this?  It's very disconcerting to think that git might spontaneously introduce erroneous changes of its own accord.

Comment: If it were Git doing that, the change would probably be staged. I’m not familiar with Xcode, but my random guess is that something (Xcode?) was watching for changes, and when the .xcodeproj became invalid because of the merge conflict markers, it deleted Package.resolved. Have you tried resolving the conflict and finishing the merge?

Comment: Might also be good to check whether one of the branches has it in .gitignore. Maybe that can result in this. (`git log -p .gitignore '**/.gitignore'` on the merge)

Comment: @Ry- Ah, you're right, I think - I quit XCode and now the thing is no longer happening.  Thanks!  If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.